# Read files for last 2 months only in directory, sub-directories

Tags: python, windows

I have > 6 months of files in a folder and sub folders, currently I can open & read all the files and write it to a csv file, however, i would like to open and read files that were created only in last 2 months.

This is the code that I am using to open and read all files-

```
for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(dirSelected):
    for filename in files:
        if fnmatch(filename, "*.CST"):
            f = open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'r+')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.getctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get your file's timestamp and then you can compare it to a date two months in the past, i.e.:

```
import datetime
import os

root_dir = "."  # whatever your target directory is
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()  # get our current date and time
past_date = current_date - datetime.timedelta(days=60)
# you can account for month length if needed, this is a 60 days in the past approximation

for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if filename[-4:].lower() == ".cst":  # we're only interested in .cst files
            # get the filename's path relative to the root dir
            target_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            # get the file's timestamp:
            c_ts = os.path.getctime(target_path)  # NOTE: this works only on Windows!
            c_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c_ts)  # convert it into a datetime
            if c_date >= past_date:  # if created after our past date
                with open(target_path, "r+") as f:
                    # do as you will with the file handle in `f`
                    pass
```

Since you've tagged your question with `windows` I assume you're using Windows - getting the actual creation date is a bit trickier on other platforms (especially Linux).